# How to disable mongodb connection logs?

Tags: mongodb, docker

**Our mongodb relication has many logs like this:**

```
>     2017-11-24T02:15:50.679+0000 I ACCESS   [conn6537] Successfully authenticated as principal stats on stats
>     2017-11-24T02:15:50.679+0000 I ACCESS   [conn6535] Successfully authenticated as principal stats on stats
>     
>     2017-11-24T02:15:51.150+0000 I -        [conn6535] end connection :49982 (13 connections now open)
>     2017-11-24T02:15:51.150+0000 I -        [conn6536] end connection 
> 
> 2017-11-24T02:33:09.187+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted
> from 2017-11-24T02:33:09.187+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection
> accepted from 2017-11-24T02:33:09.187+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1]
> connection accepted from
```

**Our config:**

db.getLogComponents();

```
{
        "verbosity" : 0,
        "accessControl" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "command" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "control" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "executor" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "geo" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "index" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "network" : {
                "verbosity" : -1,
                "asio" : {
                        "verbosity" : -1
                },
                "bridge" : {
                        "verbosity" : -1
                }
        },
        "query" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "replication" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "sharding" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "storage" : {
                "verbosity" : -1,
                "journal" : {
                        "verbosity" : -1
                }
        },
        "write" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "ftdc" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "tracking" : {
                "verbosity" : -1
        }
}
```

How can I disable these logs? Thank you!

Comment: which MongoDB version, you are using?

Comment: First thing , why you want  to disable mongodb connection logs?

Answer (score 4):

With "[quiet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/)" configuration parameter (not recommended) you get rid of:

- "Successfully authenticated as..."
- "connection accepted from ..."

but "end connection ..." still stays there and there is no way to remove it, without changing source code. You can always ask developers to change [code](http://mongo/src/mongo/transport/service_entry_point_impl.cpp) to

```
if (!quiet) { 
  const auto word = (connectionCount == 1 ? " connection"_sd : "connections"_sd);
  log() << "end connection " << remote << " (" << connectionCount << word << " now open)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB BOL [db.getLogComponents()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getLogComponents/) Returns the current verbosity settings. The verbosity settings determine the amount of Log Messages that MongoDB produces for each log message component.

As the default `db.getLogComponents()` returns a document with the verbosity settings.

```
{
   "verbosity" : 0,
   "accessControl" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "command" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "control" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "geo" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "index" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "network" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "query" : {
      "verbosity" : 2
   },
   "replication" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "sharding" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   },
   "storage" : {
      "verbosity" : 2,
      "journal" : {
         "verbosity" : -1
      }
   },
   "write" : {
      "verbosity" : -1
   }
}
```

If you want to modify any of these (verbosity) settings , you can configure the `systemLog.verbosity` and `systemLog.component.<name>.verbosity` settings in the configuration file or set the `logComponentVerbosity` parameter using the setParameter command or use the `db.setLogLevel()` method.

**As the verbosity level can range from 0 to 5:**

**1.** `0` is the MongoDB’s default log verbosity level, to include
    Informational messages.

**2.** `1` to `5` increases the verbosity level to
        include Debug messages.

For further your ref [systemLog.verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.verbosity) and [Log Messages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/)